# Error during loading leiningen project in IDEA with Cursive plugin

Tags: intellij-idea, clojure, leiningen, cursive

I have a multi module project.
When I try to load root project.clj there is error occurred:

```
Error reading <path to module project.clj>.
Error loading <path to root project.clj>
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /clojure/clojures.txt (No such file or directory), compiling:(project.clj:2:51)
        /clojure/clojures.txt (No such file or directory)
```

The cjojures.txt is for `lein monolith` plugin.
I have no idea why leiningen try to load clojures.txt from root. I mean project directory has name 'clojure' anв this directory under the my home directory, but the leiningen thinks that it under the root directory.

I use Idea 2018.3.4, Leiningen 2.8.3, Cursive v1.8.1-eap2-2018.3. All are working on macOS Mojave

Comment: usually these path are relative paths. please see if you are using absolute path.